# Functional alternative to "let"

Tags: clojure

I find myself writing a lot of clojure in this manner:

```
(defn my-fun [input]
  (let [result1 (some-complicated-procedure input) 
        result2 (some-other-procedure result1)]
    (do-something-with-results result1 result2)))
```

This `let` statement seems very... imperative. Which I don't like. In principal, I could be writing the same function like this:

```
(defn my-fun [input]
    (do-something-with-results (some-complicated-procedure input) 
                               (some-other-procedure (some-complicated-procedure input)))))
```

The problem with this is that it involves recomputation of `some-complicated-procedure`, which may be arbitrarily expensive. Also you can imagine that `some-complicated-procedure` is actually  a series of nested function calls, and then I either have to write a whole new function, or risk that changes in the first invocation don't get applied to the second:

E.g. this works, but I have to have an extra shallow, top-level function that makes it hard to do a mental stack trace:

```
(defn some-complicated-procedure [input] (lots (of (nested (operations input))))) 
(defn my-fun [input]
    (do-something-with-results (some-complicated-procedure input) 
                               (some-other-procedure (some-complicated-procedure input)))))
```

E.g. this is dangerous because refactoring is hard:

```
(defn my-fun [input]
    (do-something-with-results (lots (of (nested (operations (mistake input))))) ; oops made a change here that wasn't applied to the other nested calls
                               (some-other-procedure (lots (of (nested (operations input))))))))
```

Given these tradeoffs, I feel like I don't have any alternatives to writing long, imperative `let` statements, but when I do, I cant shake the feeling that I'm not writing idiomatic clojure. Is there a way I can address the computation and code cleanliness problems raised above *and* write idiomatic clojure? Are imperitive-ish `let` statements idiomatic?

Comment: A more specific example might be helpful. I believe the answer would depend on what `some-complicated-procedure` and `some-other-procedure` and `do-something-with-results` are doing. But as mentioned below by @andy_fingerhut and @Charles Duffy, this is idiomatic in terms of `let`.

Comment: Yes, `let` is idiomatic. If it helps you sleep better at night, think of `(let [a (f x), b (g a y)] (h a b))` as syntactic sugar for `((fn [a] ((fn [b] (h a b)) (g a y))) (f x))`, if i managed to get my parenthesis correct, because that's essentially what it is. In other words, your instinct of using nested functions to bind a results to names is what `let` formalizes in an easier to read format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kind of `let` statements you describe might remind you of imperative code, but there is nothing imperative about them.  Haskell has similar statements for binding names to values within bodies, too.

Comment: I _would_ argue that there's something imperative about them insofar as they have a well-defined order-of-operations, as opposed to evaluating the bound names only as-and-when needed. On the other hand, they're certainly idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

If your situation really needs a bigger hammer, there are some bigger hammers that you can either use or take for inspiration.  The following two libraries offer some kind of binding form (akin to `let`) with a localized memoization of results, so as to perform only the necessary steps and reuse their results if needed again:  [Plumatic Plumbing](https://github.com/plumatic/plumbing), specifically the Graph part; and Zach Tellman's [Manifold](https://aleph.io/), whose `let-flow` form furthermore orchestrates asynchronous steps to wait for the necessary inputs to become available, and to run in parallel when possible.  Even if you decide to maintain your present course, their docs make good reading, and the code of Manifold itself is educational.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same question when I looked at this code I wrote

```
(let [user-symbols (map :symbol states)
      duplicates (for [[id freq] (frequencies user-symbols) :when (> freq 1)] id)]
  (do-something-with duplicates))
```

You'll note that `map` and `for` are lazy and will not be executed until `do-something-with` is executed. It's also possible that not all (or even not any) of the `states` will be mapped or the frequencies calculated. It depends on what `do-something-with` actually requests of the sequence returned by `for`. This is very much functional and idiomatic functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

i guess the simplest approach to keep it functional would be to have a pass-through state to accumulate the intermediate results. something like this:

```
(defn with-state [res-key f state]
  (assoc state res-key (f state)))

user> (with-state :res (comp inc :init) {:init 10})
;;=> {:init 10, :res 11}
```

so you can move on to something like this:

```
(->> {:init 100}
     (with-state :inc'd (comp inc :init))
     (with-state :inc-doubled (comp (partial * 2) :inc'd))
     (with-state :inc-doubled-squared (comp #(* % %) :inc-doubled))
     (with-state :summarized (fn [st] (apply + (vals st)))))

;;=> {:init 100,
;;    :inc'd 101,
;;    :inc-doubled 202,
;;    :inc-doubled-squared 40804,
;;    :summarized 41207}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `let` form is a perfectly functional construct and can be seen as syntactic sugar for calls to anonymous functions. We can easily write  a recursive macro to implement our own version of `let`:

```
(defmacro my-let [bindings body]
  (if (empty? bindings)
    body
    `((fn [~(first bindings)]
        (my-let ~(rest (rest bindings)) ~body))
      ~(second bindings))))
```

Here is an example of calling it:

```
(my-let [a 3
         b (+ a 1)]
        (* a b))
;; => 12
```

And here is a `macroexpand-all` called on the above expression, that reveal how we implement `my-let` using anonymous functions:

```
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(my-let [a 3
                                        b (+ a 1)]
                                       (* a b)))
;; => ((fn* ([a] ((fn* ([b] (* a b))) (+ a 1)))) 3)
```

Note that the expansion doesn't rely on `let` and that the bound symbols become parameter names in the anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

As others write, *let* is actually perfectly functional, but at times it can **feel** imperative. It's better to become fully comfortable with it.

You might, however, want to kick the tires of my little library [tl;dr](https://github.com/clojureman/tldr) that lets you write code like for example

```
(compute 
     (+ a b c)
 where
     a (f b)
     c (+ 100 b))
```